# scroll for page anchors on mobile and in respect to the height of different element than on large view

Tags: jquery, mobile, scroll

I have the following code which produces nice scrolling effect to page anchors on viewports bigger than 768px (included). It places the target of anchor nicely below the height of `#navbarTop`. However, on small viewports it is a different element, `#menuMobile`, which height should be respected. The `#menu Mobile` is a list of links which unfolds when clicking on humburger menu button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var headerHeight, part, place;

function getOffsets() {
    headerHeight = $('#navbarTop').height(); 
}

$(window).load(getOffsets).resize(getOffsets);

$(function () {
    $('.headerAnchor').click(function () {
        part = $(this).attr('href');
        place = $(part).offset().top - headerHeight;

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: place
        }, 'slow');

        return false;
    });
 });
});
```

And html for main menu:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbarTop">
   <div class="navbar-header">
       <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" id="brand">Curriculum Vitae</a>
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
   </div>
     <ul id="menuMobile" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse">
       <li><a class="headerAnchor" href="#data">Dane <span>kontaktowe</span></a></li>
       <li><a class="headerAnchor" href="#aspirations">Aspiracje <span>zawodowe</span></a></li>
       <li><a class="headerAnchor" href="#qualifications">Kwalifikacje</a></li>
       <li><a class="headerAnchor" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
       <li><a class="headerAnchor" href="#experience">Historia <span>zatrudnienia<span></a></li>
       <li><a class="headerAnchor" href="#education">Wykształcenie</a></li>
       <li><a class="headerAnchor" href="#skills">Umiejętności</a></li> 
     </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to adjust the JS code to be able to have good scrolling effect on mobile view - in respect to the height of `#menuMobile` which stays open all the time after the menu button is clicked. However, I cannot get the proper effect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var headerHeight, part, place;

function getOffsets() {
    headerHeight = $('#navbarTop').height(); 
    menuMobileHeight = $('#menuMobile').height();
}

$(window).load(getOffsets).resize(getOffsets);

$(function () {
    $('.headerAnchor').click(function () {
        part = $(this).attr('href');
        place = $(part).offset().top - headerHeight;
        placeMobile = $(part).offset().top - menuMobileHeight;

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: place
        }, 'slow');

        if ($(window).width() < 768) { 
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: placeMobile
            }, 'slow');
        }

        return false;
    });
 });
});
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution for getting the proper dimensions for scrolling on different sizes by writing the code in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var headerHeight, part, place;

  function getOffsets() {
    headerHeight = $('#navbarTop').height(); 
    menuMobileHeight = $('#menuMobile').height() + 50;
  }

  $(window).load(getOffsets).resize(getOffsets);

  $(function () {
    $('.headerAnchor').click(function () {
        part = $(this).attr('href');
        place = $(part).offset().top - headerHeight;
        placeMobile = $(part).offset().top - menuMobileHeight;

        if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: place
         }, 'slow');
        }   

        if ($(window).width() < 768) { 
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: placeMobile
            }, 'slow');
        }

        return false;
    });
  });
});
```